# clear local storage on close browser or Tab

Tags: javascript, angular

i have done lots of R&D for this but not get proper solution. i want to do clear local storage only on close browser/tab not on refresh page. pls help me. i'll try with @HostListener('window:unload') and window.onload.

Comment: Why not use `sessionStorage`? Sounds like this might fit your needs better.

Comment: thanks @aabbccsmith

Answer (score 1):

Replace `localStorage` with [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Job done :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: you can use `beforeunload` event

- on `beforeunload` event you can WRITE to `localStorage` unload timestamp
- on `load` you can check, if there is an unload timestamp, and diff with now more than 5 seconds (filter page refreshes) you can clear you storage